# I need Rotate Matrix Elements of array using underscore.js. I have the solution but code is huge I want to short it down?

Tags: javascript

I otate Matrix Elements of array using underscore.js. I have the solution but code is huge I want to short it down ?

Function for circular shift of arrays

```js
function circularShift(mat) {
  let R, C;
  R = mat.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    C = mat[i].length;
  }
  let m = R, n = C;
  let row = 0, col = 0, prev = 0, curr = 0;

  if (row + 1 == m || col + 1 == n)
    return;

  prev = mat[row + 1][col];
  for (let i = col; i < n; i++) {
    curr = mat[row][i];
    mat[row][i] = prev;
    prev = curr;
  }
  row++;
  for (let i = row; i < m; i++) {
    curr = mat[i][n - 1];
    mat[i][n - 1] = prev;
    prev = curr;
  }
  n--;
  if (row < m) {
    for (let i = n - 1; i >= col; i--) {
      curr = mat[m - 1][i];
      mat[m - 1][i] = prev;
      prev = curr;
    }
  }
  m--;
  if (col < n) {
    for (let i = m - 1; i >= row; i--) {
      curr = mat[i][col];
      mat[i][col] = prev;
      prev = curr;
    }
  }
  col++;

  var finalArr = [];
  for (i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    finalArr.push(mat[i]);
  }

  console.log(finalArr)
}

//var arr = [[0, 0, 1, 2], [1, 0, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0, 1]];
var arr = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]];

console.log(arr);
circularShift(arr);
```

My output is below I would like the same out with very less code using underscore or loadash

Input

```
1    2    3
4    5    6
7    8    9
```

Output:

```
4    1    2
7    5    3
8    9    6
```

One by one rotate all rings of elements, starting from the outermost. To rotate a ring, we need to do following. 1) Move elements of top row. 2) Move elements of last column. 3) Move elements of bottom row. 4) Move elements of first column. Repeat above steps for inner ring while there is an inner ring.

Comment: How is this circular shift?

Comment: Thanks for replying Saharsh. I may not be able to explain it better but I have the correct output with the  code but I am looking optimize the code. If you will run the code snippet you will get the idea what i am trying to achieve. Rotate Matrix Elements

Comment: So shift need to happen with exactly 1 index? And what about elements inside? i.e., `4x4` matrix.

Comment: One by one rotate all rings of elements, starting from the outermost. To rotate a ring, we need to do following.
    1) Move elements of top row.
    2) Move elements of last column.
    3) Move elements of bottom row.
    4) Move elements of first column.
Repeat above steps for inner ring while there is an inner ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could only move parts of the array, like in the below example,

> ```
> |1    2|-> 3
>  4    5    6
>  7    8    9
> ```

then you could take the values of `i` and `j` as start values for the next side.

```js
function circularShift(matrix) {
    var result = matrix.map(a => a.slice()),
        i = 0,
        j = 0;

    for (; j < matrix[i].length - 1; j++) result[i][j + 1] = matrix[i][j];
    for (; i < matrix.length - 1;    i++) result[i + 1][j] = matrix[i][j];
    for (; j > 0;                    j--) result[i][j - 1] = matrix[i][j];
    for (; i > 0;                    i--) result[i - 1][j] = matrix[i][j];
    return result;
}

var arr = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]];

console.log(arr.map(a => a.join(' ')).join('\n'));
console.log(circularShift(arr).map(a => a.join(' ')).join('\n'));
```

Comment: Thanks Nina for the answer But is there any possibility to avoid so many loops. Somebody at work told me that it can be done with 1 loop or by using underscore or lodash.

Comment: please ask where you got this answer.